# Load file into jquery dialog

Tags: php, jquery-dialog

I just confused with `jquery dialog` and with `php form submit`

I have two forms, `page1.php` and `page2.php`

In `page1.php`, I have `<a>` link

```
<a id="addNew"> Add New </a>
<div id="myDiv"> 
       <!-- load 'page2.php' file using this div --> 
</div>
```

and when I click this link , load `page2.php` file in jquery dialog with form values.

This is my script

```
<script>
   $("#addNew").click(function() {
       $("#myDiv").load('page2.php').dialog({modal:true}); 
   });
</script>
```

These scripts works fine load with `page2.php` file.

Now my question is,

when I submit form values of `page2.php` it will be `re-directed` to `page2.php`.
But I wants to stay with my `page1.php`.

How to I achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as how you didn't provide a form, one can only make assumptions.

```
<form id="some_form" action="page2.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user_name"/>
    //a collection of form elements
<form>
```

Then use ajax, and capture the form submit event, while preventing it from it's default action

```
$(document).on('submit', '#some_form', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //stop form from redirecting, also stops sending of data
    var $this = $(this); // cache form object for performance
    $.ajax({
        url: $this.prop('action'),
        type: $this.prop('method'),
        data: {
          handle_form: 'ajax',
          form_data : $this.serializeArray()//array of objects
        },
        success:function(data){
            //data is what is returned from the server if successful
        }
    });
    return false; //just another example of stopping form submit, don't need both
});
```

Then in your page2.php file, just check for the existence of a field.

```
if(isset($_POST['user_name']) && $_POST['handle_form'] == 'ajax'):

    //your form is trying to be submit
    //handle the submission
    echo 'We submit the form!'; //is the 'data' in our success function

elseif(isset($_POST['user_name']) && !isset($_POST['handle_form'])):

    //regular form submission, no ajax, no javascript.

endif;
```

Comment: See, my input form values only in the `page2.php` not in `page1.php`. `page1.php` only have link to load `jquery dialog` with `page2.php`

Comment: Yes, I've leveraged the `.on()` method which allows me to attach events to all future elements loaded into the page that match the 2nd argument, which is `#some_form`, regardless of it it existed at page load, or was added later. I've already thought of that for you.

Comment: And also I already write the code for `submit form of page2.php` using `PHP request`

Comment: None of that matters. `$_POST` would still be available in `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: If I am going this way it will affect the normal `PHP request` of `page2.php` . right?

Comment: No, simply use `if / else / endif`, and then do `isset($_POST['user_name']) && !isset($_POST['handle_form'])` in your `else`, and that way it knows that an ajax request was not sent, as we only define the handle_form parameter in our javascript. same form elements will be avilable, 100% fallback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ajaxForm](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) which will submit form using an ajax call when you loaded your page2. For example:

HTML:

```
<form id="login" action="YOUR_FILE" method="post">
    <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" /><br />

    <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pass" /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /> 
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function processJson(data) {
    // your code goes here
}
$("#login").ajaxForm({
     dataType:  'json',
     success:   processJson // what to do when call succeed 
});
```

Have a nice day!